# Transform inches to centimeters and viceversa

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I am quite new to objective-c.

I am trying to create a function that takes inches or centimetres and transform the values into the oposite metric system.

I am currently struggling on how to do a mathematical equation in objective-c given that I do not know how to set the variables accordingly. As I always get some error from XCode saying that the variable is an int but shouldn't be or the pointer is wrong and other things... basicaly... i dont know how to make math...

The intention is that I pass the string `5’11”` or `1.80 cm` as stored somewhere else and convert it to the opposite metric system.

The code below attempts to do pass inches to cm.... if we pass 5’5” the mathematical equation should be `((5 * 12) + 3) * 2.54` this is equal to `180.34` and the formated result that i look from the function is `1.80 cm`

The following code is a far as I got but it just not working for me. if anyone could please tell me how to do this operation in my code I would appreciate it.

```
- (NSString *)returnRightMetric:(NSString *)theMeasure typeOfMetricUsed:(NSString *)metricType
{
    if ([metricType isEqualToString:@"inches"]) {

    NSArray* theConvertion = [theMeasure componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                                [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"’”"]];
    NSInteger* value1 = [theConvertion[0] intValue];
    NSInteger* value2 = [theConvertion[1] intValue];

    float *number = ((value1 * 12) + value2) * 2.54;
///.....

    } else if ([metricType isEqualToString:@"cm"])
    {
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why would you use so many strings to accomplish a simple numerical transformation?  I'd have four methods, each taking a floating point number and returning a floating point number.  The names will make what's done perfectly clear.

Comment: @duffymo - Presumably he wants to be able to parse character input.

Comment: Please try adding `(float)` in the integer evaluation; such that: `float *number = (float)((value1 * 12) + value2) * 2.54;`

Comment: @tolgamorf - That would have absolutely no effect.  (Can you tell us why?)

Comment: Also remove pointers from `NSInteger` and `float`: `float number = (float)((value1 * 12) + value2) * 2.54;`

Comment: It should be noted that your parsing scheme is fragile.  If someone inputs, eg, `11"`, your algorithm will probably take an array indexing error.  And even after you fix that it would likely treat `11'` and `11"` the same.

Comment: I'd move the parsing out of the method that does the conversion.  Let that method do one thing well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray* theConvertion = [theMeasure componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                          [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"’”"]];
int value1 = [theConvertion[0] intValue];
int value2 = [theConvertion[1] intValue];

float number = ((value1 * 12) + value2) * 2.54;
NSString *formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", (number/100)];
```

So in short you need to know the difference between native/primitive type's and reference types (type that use pointers this character     --> *. This might help [Link](http://bencoffman.com/blog/2010/06/12/WhenToUseTheStarWithObjectiveC.aspx)

Comment: @JonathanThurft - Benny is pointing out (very poorly) that you mistakenly declared `number` to be a `float*` (pointer to float) rather than a `float`.  If that's the value you want to return, assign it to `result` or just use `result` instead of `number`.

Comment: :) this is because you haven't used it elsewhere. It's a warning, I'm guessing for help with code clean up.

use "number" somewhere and the warning will go away.

Comment: Thanks, Could you add how to add the number + " cm" and round the result so that your answer is complete?

Comment: @JonathanThurft I have updated the code with what I think you requested.

Answer (score 3):

The problem occurs because you use pointers in `NSInteger` and `float`. I have modified your method with the implementation for both cm and inches, as follows:

```
- (NSString *)returnRightMetric:(NSString *)theMeasure typeOfMetricUsed:(NSString *)metricType
{
    NSString *result = nil;

    if ([metricType isEqualToString:@"inches"]) {
        NSArray* theConvertion = [theMeasure componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                                  [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"’”"]];
        NSInteger value1 = [theConvertion[0] intValue];
        NSInteger value2 = [theConvertion[1] intValue];

        float number = ((value1 * 12) + value2) * 2.54;
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f cm", round(number * 100.0) / 100.0];


    } else if ([metricType isEqualToString:@"cm"]) {
        float value = [theMeasure floatValue];
        float number = value / 2.54;

        if (number > 12.0) {
            result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i’%i”", (int)floor(number / 12.0), (int)number % 12];

        } else {
            result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0’%i”", (int)round(number)];
        }

    }

    NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
    return result;
}
```

Some Test:

```
[self returnRightMetric:@"5’11”" typeOfMetricUsed:@"inches"];
[self returnRightMetric:@"180.34 cm" typeOfMetricUsed:@"cm"];
[self returnRightMetric:@"0’11”" typeOfMetricUsed:@"inches"];
[self returnRightMetric:@"27.94 cm" typeOfMetricUsed:@"cm"];
```

The output:

```
result: 180.34 cm
result: 5’11”
result: 27.94 cm
result: 0’11”
```

Answer (score 1):

After some testings from the last answer(from tolgamorf) here is the final version. To me it works perfectly.

```
- (NSString *)returnRightMetric:(NSString *)theMeasure typeOfMetricUsed:(NSString *)metricType
{
    NSString *result = nil;

    if ([metricType isEqualToString:@"inches"]) {  
        if ([theMeasure isEqualToString:@""]) {
            return @"0";
        }
        NSArray* theConvertion = [theMeasure componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                                  [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"’”"]];
        NSInteger value1 = [theConvertion[0] intValue];
        NSInteger value2 = [theConvertion[1] intValue];

        float number = ((value1 * 12) + value2) * 2.54;
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f cm", round(number * 100.0) / 100.0];


    } else if ([metricType isEqualToString:@"cm"]) {
        float value = [theMeasure floatValue];
        float number = value / 2.54;

        if (roundf( number) >= 12.0) {
            if ((int)round( number) % 12==0) {
                result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i’%i”", (int)roundf(number / 12.0), (int)round( number) % 12];
            }else{
                result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i’%i”", (int)floorf(number / 12.0), (int)round( number) % 12];
            }
        } else {
            result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0’%i”", (int)round(number)];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For today we have useful API from HealthKit:

```
let cm_q = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit(from: .centimeter), doubleValue: 180)
var inch_string = h_formatter.string(fromMeters: cm_q.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.meter()))

var inches_double = cm_q.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.inch())
let inch_q = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit(from: .inch), doubleValue: inches_double)
var cm_d = inch_q.doubleValue(for: HKUnit(from: .centimeter))
var string = h_formatter.string(fromValue: cm_d, unit: .centimeter)
```

Just copy to Playground and play converting of values from cm to inches and back. The formatter configuration:

```
let h_formatter = LengthFormatter()
h_formatter.isForPersonHeightUse = true
h_formatter.unitStyle = .short
```

In the result we have:

180cm -> "5′ 10.866″" and back to 180cm

I hope it'll help.