# Convert from inches,lbs to centimeter,kg in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem:

My app allow user choose 2 options : *`Metric or Imperial.`*

- If user select `"Metric", height(cm), weight(kg)`.
- If Select `"Imperial: height(inch) and weight (lbs)`.

I need to change value of height  from inch to centimeter and weight from lbs to kg.

**Example :**

`user input : 70 (inch) and 120 (lbs) ==> convert to 177.8 (cm) and 54.5 (kg)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question? How to [convert from inches to centimeters](http://chemistry.about.com/od/unitconversions/a/Converting-Inches-to-Centimeters.htm)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7413708/1971013

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955914/transform-inches-to-centimeters-and-viceversa

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I mean I want to convert height value from unit mesurement is Inch to centimeter. weight from lbs to kg.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about unit conversion, not programming.

Comment: @user3125692 Multiply inches by 2.54 to get cm, multiply lbs by 0.453592 to get kg...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best example of unit convert is below [link](https://github.com/HiveHicks/HHUnitConverter)..